# IE tries to save Ajax response as file

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, internet-explorer

Using Rails RJS with jQuery, I have a link with an event binding on click that does ajax call with GET and returning dataType: script (with RJS providing the response).

Works the first time in Explorer, but after that, when you click the link, it tries to save the response as a file.... Any ideas how to get around this?

Only a problem in IE.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is typically due to issues with server settings and the [HTTP headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers) being passed to the browser.  I'd particularly ensure the server is using the correct Content-Type header for the Ajax request.

Comment: Thanks Calvin, your answer led me to the solution which was the standard IE problem of needing a responds_to format.html before the format.js....

Comment: It didn't answer my question directly. The answer was to change the respond_to settings to place HTML response first in the Rails controller action. I just appreciated that he took the time to try and offer some advice.